# Modern Objective-C code - minimum iOS requirement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Can I run Modern Objective-C code on iOS 5.0?

Comment: Please be more specific about the "modern". The question will stay on the site for a long time; what's modern today will no longer be modern in a year. Are you looking for ARC? Array subscripts? New literals?..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Presumably all of the features enumerated in the WWDC 2012 sessions [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) and [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413) and which are part of Xcode's new "Convert to Modern Objective-C" refactoring tool.

Comment: @Abhinav The short answer is "yes". All of the features are supported on iOS 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Rob.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243) to determine what language features are available on what platforms.